# Why use an object when denormalising data?

Tags: firebase

In the recent blog post on [denormalising data](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html), it suggests logging all of a user's comments beneath each user like so:

```
comments: {
    comment1: true,
    comment2: true
}
```

Why is this not a list like so:

```
comments: [
    "comment1",
    "comment2",
]
```

What are the advantages? Is there any difference at all? While I'm at it, how would you go about generating unique references for these comments for a distributed app? I was imagining that with a list I'd just push them onto the end and let the array take care of the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase only ever stores objects. The JS client converts arrays into objects using the index as a key. So, for instance if you store the following array using `set`:

```js
comments: [
  "comment1",
  "comment2"
]
```

In Forge (the graphical debugger), it will show up as:

```js
comments:
   0: comment1
   1: comment2
```

Given this, storing the ID of the comment directly as a key has the advantage that you can refer to it directly in the security rules, for example, with an expression like:

```js
root.child('comments').hasChild($comment)
```

In order to generate unique references for these comments, please use `push` (https://www.firebase.com/docs/managing-lists.html):

```js
var commentsRef = new Firebase("https://<example>.firebaseio.com/comments");
var id = commentsRef.push({content: "Hello world!", author: "Alice"});
console.log(id); // Unique identifier for the comment just added.
```